# Why can't -ve and +ve ΔHeg (e-gain enthalpy) be compared?

Tags: thermodynamics

• My first confusion is why the **endothermic** one is still being called **ΔHeg** considering the definition states "*loss of energy by isolated gasious atom upon gain of an e-*"?

• Why can't I compare both? They have same dimensions right?

If the question is not clear, take it as comparison of 1st and 2nd electron gain enthalpy.